# Cannot apply multiple maven profiles at command line

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I cannot activate more than one Maven profile from command line.

I have a maven based Spring Boot project. I have 3 maven profiles within it for excluding specific java resources and other resources.

I am able to activate only one profile at a time from command line.

```
mvn clean package -P exclude-demo-service,exclude-mock-service
```

When I pass more than one profile, only one of them works. In the above , only **exclude-mock-service** works but **exclude-demo-service** does not work.

I have shared the pom.xml used for my sample project at below,
https://github.com/bsridhar123/mavenbuildtoggledemo/blob/master/pom.xml

I basically want to apply multiple profiles when running maven build.

Can someone please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Try with `mvn install -P exclude-demo-service,exclude-mock-service`

Comment: I suppose the plugin configurations overwrite each other because you define the same elements again. If those services are Spring beans I would rather use Spring profiles.

Comment: @krishnakuntala I tried mvn install -P exclude-demo-service,exclude-mock-service but I still the same issue.

Comment: @ChristianZiegler If we use Spring Profile feature to activate the beans at startup, the beans would still be part of the build artifact, tho won't be active. I want them to be excluded from the built artifact.

Comment: Yes sure, but usually that is not a Problem. Anyway, the merging of plugin configurations seems to only work for parent/child poms if configured (see combine.[self, parent] attribute of the configuration tag, so I don't see another way than making a profile that combines the configuration of the two.

Comment: Having a similar issue here; looks like always the *last* profile defined in `pom.xml` gets activated, i.e. whether I say `mvn install -Pa,b` or `mvn install -Pb,a`, profile `b` gets activated if it appears below `a` in `pom.xml`. Strange. (Possibly some merging/overwriting is happening, as suggested by @ChristianZiegler?)